# VueJS Webpack - Can't add new aliases, vue files don't load

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

So say I have the following in my .vue file:

`import VContainer from '@/styleguide/components/organisms/Container';`

I and my aliases are set up like so:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    '@': resolve('src'),
    'styles': resolve('src/styles/'),
  }
},
```

when I try to add a new alias for styleguide components:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
  'styleguide': resolve('src/styleguide/components/'),
  'styles': resolve('src/styles/'),
}
```

then try to do the following:

`import VContainer from 'styleguide/organisms/Container';`

I get the following error...

***Unable to resolve path to module***

Is there something I am missing? Prefixing it with ~ like ...`from '~styleguide/..'` doens't work either

Comment: Do you try `'styleguide': resolve('src/styleguide/components'),
  'styles': resolve('src/styles'),`

Comment: @imcvampire, the styles work absolutely fine, when importing sass files I just need to a ~styles/path/to/blah. The importing in javascript is where it is going wrong and won't work even with your change

Comment: first: do you reset webpack? second, tried with path.resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here in case people arrive at this with the same issue.

I think what you are doing absolutely *should* work, and I was debugging a similar issue for some time. I found that the fix was as simple as restarting webpack, since it seems that it doesn't "hot reload" changes to the config.

Worth double-checking, I think.